# How can I manually create a Silverlight PollingDuplex client/proxy?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, wcf, pollingduplexhttpbinding

There's lots of material explaining why using svcutil.exe (or 'add service reference') is bad - lack of testability, tight coupling etc. Manually creating a client proxy for a simple service is straightforward, you just need to manually create your interface and create a channel:

```
IMessageServiceAsync service = new ChannelFactory<IMessageServiceAsync>("BasicHttpBinding_IMessageEndpoint").CreateChannel();
```

I want to do something similar but for a Silverlight PollingDuplex client.

This appears more difficult - the generated client inherits from `System.ServiceModel.DuplexClientBase` - I assume my manually created client would also need to? Or is there a way to hookup all the client-side Duplex callback functionality without implementing this base class?

Has anyone ever tried this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible - you can use the `DuplexChannelFactory<T>` class to create a proxy in a similar way as the `ChannelFactory<T>` you had in your example, but you'll need to pass an extra parameter (typed `InstanceContext`) which will contain an implementation of the callback interface used to receive the messages from the server.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Carlos. Just out of interest, are there any other potential pitfalls that I should be aware of?

Comment: None specific to the `DuplexChannelFactory` itself; the proxy generated by Add Service Reference (subclass of `DuplexChannelBase`) is equivalent to the one created by `DuplexChannelFactory.CreateChannel()`.